# Value Provider error while injecting in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to create a Value Provider for our Core Framework.

So i've created thoses

```
export interface TexteVide {
  texte: string;
}

export const TEXTE_VIDE_VALEUR = new InjectionToken<TexteVide>('TEXTE_VIDE_VALEUR');

export const TexteVideValeurParDefaut: TexteVide = {
  texte: '(vide)'
};
```

Then i've set the providers of our Shared Module

```
{ provide: TEXTE_VIDE_VALEUR, useValue: TexteVideValeurParDefaut }
```

And finally i've injected our Shared Module in other Modules of our application to be able to inject TEXTE_VIDE_VALEUR where needed.

but i'm getting 
`Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TestsComponent: (?).`

Here is the constructor of the TestsComponent:

`constructor(private TEXTE_VIDE_VALEUR: TexteVide) {
    console.log(TEXTE_VIDE_VALEUR.texte);
}`

What's wrong in my implementation ? or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@Inject()` to inject an `InjectionToken`:

```
constructor(@Inject(TEXTE_VIDE_VALEUR) private texte: TexteVide) {
  console.log(texte.texte);
}
```

Comment: Ok but do i really need this injection token? i've seen this in other libs, so i've created it the same way. But what is the difference between regular interface injection vs token injection?

Comment: Ok i've found that i couldn't do it without the injectiontoken.